# Configurable product with swatch AND dropdown attributes changes dropdown workflow

Tags: product, configurable-product, magento2.4.5, configurable-swatches, configurable-product-options

**Preconditions and environment**

Magento version 2.4.5

**Steps to reproduce**

Create a configurable product with only dropdown attribute - For example https://magento-802601-3429172.cloudwaysapps.com/only-dropdown-configurable.html

Create a configurable product with only swatch attribute - For example https://magento-802601-3429172.cloudwaysapps.com/only-swatch-configurable.html

Create a configurable product with Swatch AND Dropdown attribute - For example https://magento-802601-3429172.cloudwaysapps.com/mix-dropdown-and-swatch-configurable.html

**Expected result**

This product makes the options required. Workflow = when you press higher level dropdown, you need to input all attributes again. LOGIC = GOOD

This product makes the options not required. Workflow = when you press another level, you do not need to input all other attributes. LOGIC = GOOD

This product makes the options not required including the dropdown attributes. So this must be a bug or there must be somewhere a place to CHOOSE the workflow?

Must be DROPDOWN = REQUIRED, SWATCH = NOT REQUIRED